# Pyspark - pivot dataframe

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have this dataframe in pyspark:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
("TenantId", "TennatId_1"),
("TimeGenerated", "2023-04-17T11:50:51.9013145Z"),
("ActivityType", "Connection"),
("CorrelationId", "608dd49a"),
("UserName", "test_1@test.cloud"),
("Name", "Name1"),
("Source", "Client"),
("Parameters", "{}"),
("SourceSystem", "Azure"),
("Type", "Check"),
("_ResourceId", "/subscriptions/5286ce"),
("TenantId", "TennatId_2"),
("TimeGenerated", "2023-04-17T11:50:51.944022Z"),
("ActivityType", "Connection"),
("CorrelationId", "11c0d75f0000"),
("UserName", "test_2@test.cloud"),
("Name", "Name2"),
("Source", "Client"),
("Parameters", "{}"),
("SourceSystem", "Azure"),
("Type", "Check"),
("_ResourceId", "/subscriptions/5286ce38-272f-4c54")], ["name", "rows"])
```

And I want to make pivot on it.

I have tried below expression:

```
pivoted_df = df.groupBy("name") \
           .pivot("name") \
           .agg(expr("first(rows) as rows")) \
           .orderBy("name")
```

but I'm getting this output :

[image]

and my desire output is:

[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: it's difficult to achieve the result without an ordering column. essentially, you want to group by tenant_id, but that is in a single row, not replicated for all rows of a group. to artificially create the grouping column, you'll need a row or group identifier.

Comment: thanks samkart. Understood, I can create it with the monotonically_increasing_id function from spark probably can work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupBy, Pivot` functions on name and aggregate on rows to get the desired output.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.groupBy(lit(1)).pivot("name").agg(first(col("rows"))).drop("1").show(10,False)
#+------------+-------------+-----+----------+------+------------+----------+----------------------------+-----+-----------------+---------------------+
#|ActivityType|CorrelationId|Name |Parameters|Source|SourceSystem|TenantId  |TimeGenerated               |Type |UserName         |_ResourceId          |
#+------------+-------------+-----+----------+------+------------+----------+----------------------------+-----+-----------------+---------------------+
#|Connection  |608dd49a     |Name1|{}        |Client|Azure       |TennatId_1|2023-04-17T11:50:51.9013145Z|Check|test_1@test.cloud|/subscriptions/5286ce|
#+------------+-------------+-----+----------+------+------------+----------+----------------------------+-----+-----------------+---------------------+
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
#define window
w=Window.partitionBy(lit("1")).orderBy("mid")

#add order id column and temporary window partition
df1 = df.withColumn("mid",monotonically_increasing_id()).\
  withColumn("temp_win", when(col("rows").rlike("^TennatId"),lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))).\
  withColumn("windw", sum(col("temp_win")).over(w))

#pivot and window
df1.groupBy("windw").pivot("name").agg(first(col("rows"))).drop("windw").show(10,False)

#+------------+-------------+-----+----------+------+------------+----------+----------------------------+-----+-----------------+---------------------------------+
|ActivityType|CorrelationId|Name |Parameters|Source|SourceSystem|TenantId  |TimeGenerated               |Type |UserName         |_ResourceId                      |
+------------+-------------+-----+----------+------+------------+----------+----------------------------+-----+-----------------+---------------------------------+
#|Connection  |608dd49a     |Name1|{}        |Client|Azure       |TennatId_1|2023-04-17T11:50:51.9013145Z|Check|test_1@test.cloud|/subscriptions/5286ce            |
#|Connection  |11c0d75f0000 |Name2|{}        |Client|Azure       |TennatId_2|2023-04-17T11:50:51.944022Z |Check|test_2@test.cloud|/subscriptions/5286ce38-272f-4c54|
#+------------+-------------+-----+----------+------+------------+----------+----------------------------+-----+-----------------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @notNull for your help!. I already tried that, it is correct but it returns only one row and if you check my desire output I have more rows that I need to display. I'm showing a sample but in my official dataframe I have more than 2k rows :\